# how to not include boost header file in my own header file

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I am writing a class

In the class, I use boost::graph::adjacent_list as a private member.

but I don't want my header file include boost header file, because any other file include my header file will need to include boost header file.

Is there a way can avoid include boost header file in my own header file.

I have tried forward declaration, but fails.

Comment: If someone include a file that needs Boost to work, it makes sense for that file to include Boost doesn't it? Am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't understand your reason for not wanting to include the boost header.

Comment: You are not very clear. google pimpl idiom, maybe that is somthign for you.

Comment: @KAK OP possibly wants to avoid propagating a header include that's only used as an implementation detail of the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this directly, but you can probably solve the underlying problem of not propagating an implementation detail (boost) by `pimpl`ing your class. This essentially means that you forward declare a pointer to your implementation details, which are then fully implemented just in a source file.

Answer (score 2):

If your header file is definition only, and is fully implemented in a cpp file (i.e. the header file doesn't do anything with `boost::graph::adjacent_list` then in your header, you can

- Forward declare a `bgalWrapper` struct.
- Have a pointer to that struct instead of `boost::graph::adjacent_list`
- In the CPP file that implements the header file, declare the new
  `bgalWrapper` struct (which only has a `boost::graph::adjacent_list` member)
- Create an instance of the struct in the classes ctor (and - obviously

  - clean up in the dtor).

Now each class can have a reference to the boost item without the header needing to know about boost.

There's probably a name (and wikipage) for this pattern, but it's years since I programmed C++ seriously.

Hope this helps.

**Update** What I've described is a partial implementation of the [PIMPL Idiom](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/the-c-pimpl-r1794)
*Thanks Mark B*

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but can't you define the list as a pointer variable? Then the forward declaration should succeed. You'll have to nest the namespaces though:

```
using namespace boost::graph;
class adjacent_list;
class MyClass {
    private adjacent_list<foo, bar> m_list;
}
```

Or perhaps:

```
namespace boost {
    namespace graph {
        class adjacent_list;
    }
}
class MyClass {
    private adjacent_list<foo, bar> m_list;
}
```

Then in your implementation file, just use it as a pointer:

```
#include <boost/graph/adj_list_serialize.hpp>
MyClass::MyClass() {
    m_list = new adjacency_list<foo, bar>();
}
```